# How a bundle can provide "default data" i.e. pre-filled tables in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle

I think I've a good understanding of Symfony and how bundle works.

However I've never found how to solve a simple problem: make a reusable bundle that provides data like tables/Doctrine entities pre-filled with (i.e.) all country names in the world, all provinces of Italy,  tax rates history in England and so on.

Of course the purpose is to provide forms, services and controllers relying on this data source, without the need to copy and paste tables and entities across projects.

How would you do that?

Data fixtures IMHO are not an option because an obvious reason: you are going to purge your database while it's running.

A custom command reading from a static data-source (json, YAML) and performing inserts/updates?

Comment: If you are not like doctrine fixtures only becuase of purging a database, you can use the option `--append`. As doc says: use this flag to append data instead of deleting data before loading it (deleting first is the default behavior).

Comment: That's really a good question, we have the same problem on a large project of ours. (We simply ship an install script, but that's really ugly). The ugliest part is that we need to hard code IDs into our code to reference the prefilled entities. Really looking forward to answers to this question.

Comment: @lxg -- are you familiar with Magento install/upgrade scripts? They provide a pretty versatile solution (read as: "implies significant work"). In a Magento install/upgrade script you can execute raw SQL or use the DBAL API to build tables, add data and fetch the resulting autoincrement IDs. Our convention was to insert these new autoincremented IDs into the Magento config table so we could later reference the config-key in our code (not the ids themselves). It's obviously not a perfect situation but unless your data has other unique identifiers (name, slug, uuid) how else could it be done.

Comment: @lxg also generally speaking I'd like to use UUIDs in a production project and see what practical disadvantages they bring because in most areas they seem to have a lot of advantages and one (possibly big) disadvantage (the slowdown for indexing speed due to their larger size).

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Thanks for the reference to Magento. Could you please post a link to the documentation of this component, or alternatively a link to its source code?

Comment: Here's a relevant example for Magento [install/update script](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/). The thing is the install/update scripts aren't that smart by themselves (they do have versioning control and they get run incrementally based on the module's declared version and its recorded installed version). But other than that the flexibility and configuration-keys and everything else are a byproduct of the Magento framework.

Comment: If you are working with SQL/ORM, maybe [Doctrine Migrations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) might help with updating the database.

Answer (score 10):

First step is declaring a Doctrine entity in your Bundle. I think you should create DataFixtures to populate your datas into db.

You maybe should consider to use Seeds instead of Fixtures.

Fixtures are fake datas, used to test your application

Seeds are the minimal datas required for your application to work.

Technically, these are exactly the same thing, you declare it under the "DataFixtures/" folder and you import them with the "doctrine:fixtures:load" command.

You can create a folder "Fixtures/", and a folder "Seeds/" under the folder "DataFixtures", then load your seeds with the command

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/path/to/seeds/folder --append
```

It was suggested in the comments that it may be safer, especially in production environment, to create a custom Symfony2 command to force the "--append" mode. Without this mode, your database will be purged, and you could loose your production data.

Comment: The question expicitely states that fixtures are NOT an appropriate solution. The `Seeds/` stuff sounds interesting, could you please add more details on that? Barely mentioning a folder name doesn't really help. ;) What does a “seed” look like? How is it applied? How does the mapping between a “seed” and the business logic work?

Comment: The difference between Fixtures and Seeds is a convention. A Seed is strictly the same file kind than a Fixture, but the convention defines it as a "minimal data" for the application to work, so the team knows it's necessary to load it when configuring the project. I added the command to execute to load it.

Comment: How do you handle the problem of mapping identifiers in the code? E.g. an entity needs a reference to a country entity, which is implemented as seed. Also, the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command is extremely dangerous in a live environment, if you forget the `--append` you could delete your entire database (as gremo mentioned).

Comment: I don't really see the problem of mapping identifiers. IMO you never references a database entry by it's sql identifier don't you ? If you need to refer the country "France", you should do it by it's unique slug "france", not by it's sql ID "32". I join you about the dangerousity of do:fi:lo in production, I personally double check everything I do in production env.

Comment: I *must* use an ID, (a) because it's guaranteed to be unique, (b) because of D2 methods like `$em->find("Entity", $id)` or `$em->getReference("Entity", $id)`. How should these methods work elsewise? Or do you use a service to map slugs to IDs? Then again, how does the service handle the mapping?

Comment: Unicity is guaranteed by the "unique" attribute on \@Column annotation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

I never use these D2 methods, but it seems that if you setup the $slug property with the \@Id annotation it will works.
I generally use repo methods ($em->getRepository('Country')->findOneBySlug('france');

Comment: You're right; repos should be used here. After all, your approach doesn't seem too bad. (As for `doctrine:fixtures:load`: I'd probably use an own command as a wrapper, to be on the safe side.) Could you take a few minutes to incorporate this discussion into your answer? No need to write code, just explain the major aspects of the solution, so that it serves as a blueprint for an implementation.

Comment: I think you should use the fixture mechanism, but embed it in a custom symfony command like `seed:install`. This command will simply call your "fixture/seed" script and force the `--append` option, avoiding risk of deleting data.

Comment: Use a custom command is a great idea to avoid a undesired purge purge, I will syntethize the discussion in original post asap.

Comment: I udpated original post with your constructive comments, thanks.

Comment: I have now awarded the bounty to this answer, because it describes a valid approach to solve the problem, and it introduced the idea of using `doctrine-fixtures` with a different type of data structure. I must admit that I'm nevertheless a bit disappointed about the quality of the post … a really great answer would have explained more and provided more details. Anyway, the important thing is, we have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes you're using composer to install your bundles (and you really exclude fixtures as an option).

What you can do, is make an SQL export of the data you want, and make sure it uses INSERT IGNORE INTO, and get the correct unique constraints.

Then you save that file somewhere in your bundle, in a "data" or "fixtures" folder.
so your path to that file will be like:
"vendor/company/epicbundle/data/countries.sql"

What you then can do, is add post-insert and post-update commands in your composer.json, that looks like this:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "php app/console doctrine:query:sql \"$(cat vendor/company/epicbundle/data/countries.sql)\""
]
```

If you only want it to run on install, you only add it there, if you sometimes update the sql file, you also add it to the post-update-cmd.

Please note that this solution only works if people don't temper with the table names, otherwise the queries will fail.

If you want a more save/stable solution, you can write your own post-install script in Symfony that uses the entity manager, and there you can use, for example, a csv file, and insert/update it row by row.

Comment: This solution only deals with ORM-backed Docrine, ODM is not supported. I think it's not a really good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I think that raw SQL is very error prone, and it's not really testable. Also, the `post-install-cmd` invokes a shell command, which “doesn't feel right” (sorry, can't explain in brief). As for the fixtures: “Normal” fixtures are not a solution, but I must admit that Paul Andrieux' approach of using “custom” fixtures is not that bad. But I'm still open to other solutions.

Comment: @kix: It is true that this answer is Doctrine ORM specific, but the entire scope of this question/discussion has been D2-ORM specific so far, therefore I would not penalize the answer only because of this.

Comment: @lxg, actually, I don't see if the author has stated that he's using ORM or ORM exactly, but he did state that a reusable bundle is needed. This leads to a conclusion that an ORM-only solution wouldn't be satisfactory.

Comment: Yeah, but he mentions tables. ;) But you're right, a really good solution would be agnostic about the storage backend.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, anything you could implement would surely rely on persistence mechanisms used in your ORM/ODM/whatever. So, you'll end up implementing a typical fixture loading mechanism, at least partially: you'd execute code that saves some provided data; if it's serialized you'd do XML/JSON/YAML parsing (but this is just a technicality) and persist the results into the database.

Thus, it's not bad to stick with Doctrine Fixtures. They are programmable and extensible (you can even fetch your data from the web upon loading).

As stated in @paul-andrieux's answer, if you are worried about data loss (e.g. your bundle's seeds are loaded when the end user's DB is already up), you should use `doctrine:fixtures:load --append` and let the constraints do their job (like, in a country names table you'd have a unique constraint on country name or even a 'slug') so that inserting duplicate rows silently fails inserting a single entity, in case if your bundle has updated the country list, and the end user had a previous version.

If you really worry about your end users' data you could write a wrapper for the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command that would have the `--append` flag always on and register it as a separate command. (You could run needed migrations there, too)

@lxg's hard-coded IDs problem is solvable, too. Try using [natural keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) where applicable (e.g. the `countries` table would have a `slug` primary key that would be `great-britain` for Grean Britain). This way your searches would be pretty easy: `$em->find('\MyBundle\Country', 'great-britain');`. If you cannot come up with a natural key, then maybe the entity is not really needed for the end user.

UPD. Here's an article that could be useful: http://www.craftitonline.com/2014/09/doctrine-migrations-with-schema-api-without-symfony-symfony-cmf-seobundle-sylius-example/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, especially on the natural keys. For country, it would be even pretty simple, as you can use the numeric ISO 3166 codes, same with currencies and ISO 4217.

Comment: With fixtures (and a custom command to be safe) you also need some way of updating data when needed (say another country added to the world ;)) when updating the bundle; how this can be managed? Can be automatic? I know that migrations are used to handle schema changes, but what about data change?

Comment: @gremo, your keys should not allow adding duplicate data. Removal of data can be handled with some kind of a wrapper around the loading mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the bundle embedded the entities that will be loaded via the ORM/ODM using their built-in commands (like `doctrine:schema:update`, `doctrine:migration:diff`, ...) and provides a custom command that load the required fixtures using the ODM/ORM

This command can read the fixtures in multiple way (parsing yaml, xml, raw sql, dql, ...), it is just a matter of taste. Tones of bundles, parser, ... exist for those tasks.

In your documentation, you just have to state in a clear way that the developer must run this command after your bundle installation and schema update.